# VBA Userform Listbox Headers from sql query

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I have a listbox that works as expected except it does not contain headers and I dont know how I can get this as it doesnt seem straight forward.

I have 20 fields to populate meaning the user has to scroll across to see all fields so don't think there is an option to add labels separately as a kind of hack. also as I use SQL in this the query can change based on user input.

I think I need to so something around after the Rs.open to get the headers but i dont have a clue!

Example Code below in a button - I have not included error handlers as trying to keep it simple

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Svalue As String, scolumn As String, stSQL As String
scolumn = UF1.cmbSearchColumn.Value 'COMBOBOX VALUE (FIELD) 
Svalue = UF1.txtSearchB.Value 'COMBOBOX VALUE (CRITERIA )

''Set database connection string. This connects excel with SQL database
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
        cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Data Source = ServerName;Initial Catalog = DatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

  'open connection to db
    cn.Open
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.ActiveConnection = cn

 If scolumn = "" Then
stSQL = "select top 10 * from  Databasename.dbo.TableName"
Else
"select top 10 * from Databasename.dbo.TableName where [" & scolumn & "] = '" & Svalue & "' ORDER BY Date DESC "
End if
 rs.Source = stSQL
    rs.Open

With Listbox1
    .ColumnCount = rs.Fields.count
 '   .ColumnHeads = True ' gives blanks as nothing defined for the headers
    .List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
End with

  rs.Close
    cn.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Add an extra row to the listbox. iterate recordset header manually and write column names to the list - header will look like any other row and be selectable. Alternatively dump recordset to the worksheet, add extra row and write headers and use it as listbox source.

Comment: Thanks Victor, I thought this but I would need to have to freeze that row which I don't think is possible. Also not sure how how to do it.spme sample code would really help.

Answer (score 0):

I use two approaches. First one is to add headers from the recordset as its own row into the listbox by manually adding a row and iterating field names. That treats header row as a regular data row and it does not freeze it. That works well for shorter lists and you have to work around the first row being a header if you need to do something after listbox.click

The second one is to use a helper worksheet (I usually use add-ins and then I just add a hidden helper worksheet to the add-in workbook and delete it afterwards), dump the recordset into the worksheet and add a header row to the sheet manually. That works best for larger recordsets and also freezes the header row in the listbox.

Below is sample code, however I use it in class object to make it more manageable, add functionality and make it easier to reuse.

```
Private Sub paintListBox()
    dim yourWorksheet as worksheet
    set yourWorksheet = thisworkbook.sheets.add
    'yourWorksheet.visible = xlHidden
    applyFormatting("@|0|yyyy-mm-dd") 
    'You can also apply formatting by column with this option, 
    'but it has to match column count. 
    'In this example first column is text, then number, then date
    addColumnHeaders
    yourListBox.ColumnHeads = True
    yourWorksheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset yourRecordset
    yourListbox.RowSource = "[" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "]" & yourWorksheet.Name & "!" & yourworksheet.UsedRange.Address 
    'you may have to determine target range separately
    'you may need to handle 0 record count case separately
end sub

Private Sub addColumnHeaders()
Dim I As Long
For I = 0 To yourRecordset.Fields.Count - 1
    yourWorksheet.Cells(1, I + 1) = Replace(Trim(yourRecordset.Fields(I).Name), "'", vbNullString)
Next
End Sub

Private Sub applyFormating(byval formatMap as string)
    Dim I As Long
    Dim Arr
    ReDim Arr(yourRecordset.Fields.Count - 1)
    If formatMap <> vbNullString Then
    Arr = Split(formatMap, "|")
    End If
    For I = 0 To yourRecordset.Fields.Count - 1
        yourWorksheet.Columns(I + 1).NumberFormat = Arr(I)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this although as I don't want a sheet for this whenever I delete it. The rowsource no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim f As ADODB.Field
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False


  cn.connectionString = _
                 "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                 "Data Source=F:\Book1.xlsx;" & _
                 "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES';"
    ' Extracting data from the worksheet that has the table of rows that we want
  cn.Open
  rs.ActiveConnection = cn
  rs.Source = "select  * from [sheet1$]"

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 rs.Open
 For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1

 With Me.ListBox1
   .ColumnCount = rs.Fields.Count
   .List = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
   .ColumnHeads = clist(Replace(Trim(rs.Fields(i).Name), "'", vbNullString))

End With
Next i

 rs.Close
 cn.Close
```

how that could be solved as I don't have chance here in my written code to ierate .

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33952302)